# Is there a function in CGAL that removes the holes from a alphashape?

Tags: cgal, alpha-shape

Im trying to remove the holes from a alphashape to get a similar function as MATLABs boundary.m. The code Im using is basically the example from CGALs [documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/index.html).

[image: 2D Alpha Shapes]

Imageexample with alphashape to the left and boundary to the right:

[image: Imageexample with alphashape to the left and boundary to the right.]